# Use specific key to connect to jump host without modifying ssh config file

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to write a script that connect to a linux server by using an other one as a ProxyJump:

```
ssh -J root@proxyhost root@target
```

I have two different keys (actually ssh certificate) and I would like to tell ssh to use one for the proxy host and the other for the target. I know I could modify the ssh config for that but I would like to specify it on the command line so I don't have to rely on a valid ssh configuration.

So I'm looking for something like:

```
ssh -i proxyhostkey -J root@proxyhost -i targetkey root@target
```

The ssh man page of the `-J` options says (emphasis mine):

> Note that configuration directives supplied on the command-line
> **generally** apply to the destination host and not any specified jump
> hosts.  Use ~/.ssh/config to specify configuration for jump hosts.

Is it possible to do want I want ? Or do I have to ensure that the `~/.ssh/config` file will be correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you'll have to either

- use two `-i` parameters and allow ssh to offer *both* keys to both servers (the order of `-i` versus `-J` doesn't matter);
- or replace `-J` with a manual ProxyCommand:

  ```
  ssh target -oProxyCommand="ssh proxyhost -i ~/otherkey -W %h:%p" -i ~/thiskey
  ```